# Which C++ opensource projects have very high code quality?

Tags: c++, open-source

I would like to list some of the best quality projects in the opensource C++ world. I know the question is very broad, but it can serve as a good resource for learning from top quality examples.

Comment: I'd say the linux kernel for C code, but 'very high quality' is pretty subjective there :)

Comment: I'm aware of the subjectivity... but I don't know how to formulate this question without subjectivity. I think is really useful anyway.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109684/what-are-some-examples-of-exceptional-c-open-source-code, among many others.

Comment: I suspected it. Well I've been searching this and the "suggestions" didn't tell anything!!!! Is not first time I post a duplicate and I don't know how to avoid it effectively

Comment: Define quality: robustness, performance, flexibility, expressiveness, portability, modularity, ... ? If you don't attempt such objective measures then you're likely to get a whole load of opinions and personal preferences.

Comment: Actually I think is inevitable to give personal preferences here. I understand that questions shouldn't be "subjective" but sometimes they are informative just like that. Ironically, among the most popular questions in SO are the most subjective ones. Answering your question, I thing that any of those qualities are a base for argumenting best projects.

Answer (score 9):

[Boost](http://www.boost.org/), [FastFormat](http://www.fastformat.org/), [Loki](http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/), [Pantheios](http://www.pantheios.org/), [POCO](http://www.pocoproject.org/), [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/), [STLSoft](http://www.stlsoft.org/)

Answer (score 7):

[Boost](http://www.boost.org/) is (are) supposed to be very good.

Comment: Please mention why Boost is very good.

Answer (score 4):

Try [STL](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/),  [Boost](http://www.boost.org) and [Loki](http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/) for a start.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest looking at Inkscape - not that it is necessarily of the best quality but fairly big and stable. Depends what you are after really.

Comment: I agree. I've already enjoyed its code.

Answer (score 1):

The boost library :)

Answer (score 1):

[KDE](http://techbase.kde.org) is one of the biggest open source C++ project out there. Being open source, code quality is dependent on the contributors, but the people writing the core libraries are very good technically, so you will find some extremely good code there.

[Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/) is a big chunk of C++, portable to many embedded and non embedded platforms, backed up by a company. You should find some excellent code in there as well.

Comment: I agree completely about Qt... but in spite I have never looked at kde's code I have had really bad experience with it. Can a good code produce such an unusable software?